# Best data structure for lookups

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have a source-set of, lets say 1M Guids. I have another "dest-set" of, lets say 1k Guids.
I want to go through my source set and see check for existance in the dest-set.

My question is the best data structure for the dest-set. Looking quickly on [this](http://net-informations.com/faq/general/dictionary-list.htm), dictionary has superior performance for lookups. Since I only have a single guid to look for, Id store it like [key,null].

Is this a correct approach? Are there any better data structure?

Comment: Check out `HashSet<T>`.

Comment: Best for what? `HashSet<T>` would be the default choice for fast random lookups, but it is a general class that need to perform *well enough* for many use cases. If you have a specialized use case you may be able to get better performance or memory usage with a custom solution.

Comment: @juharr: Thanks. If you write that as an answer I can mark it as the solution .,..or JonasH... I dont care. Thanks guys

Comment: Curious what faulty Guid generator youre using that means you have to double check the guid it made isn't already generated recently! :D

Comment: I dont use a guid generator, its two different sets in two data sources

Comment: If you know that source is bigger than dest, it's better iterate dest set (1k iterations vs 1M) and look in the source to match.

Comment: I was just curious abou the datastructure, 
Im thinking of using the ExceptWith-method or somthing like that